How to understand "excusare Baeticis contra unum hominem advocationem"?
Pliny writes letter 1.6 to Octavius Rufus, who has asked him to appear in court against the Baetici, which he declines to do:

Etenim, sicut fas est mihi, praesertim te exigente, excusare Baeticis contra unum hominem advocationem, ...

Translated (J.B. Firth, 1900):

It is open to me, especially as you press me to do so, to decline to act on behalf of the Baetici against a single individual ...

I think my difficulty lies in the construction of excuso. I can't find a relevant example in Lewis & Short (which is admittedly difficult to parse). My Latin–Swedish dictionary gives (translated by me):

a) abs. give excusing reasons or circumstances, excuse oneself, alqd give smth as an excuse, excuse oneself with (valetudinem; inopiam; propinquitatem), with quod and acc.inf. b) for given reasons decline, deny, alqd

Gaffiot quotes Tacitus:

3 décliner avec excuses, s'excuser de ne pas faire qqch : reditum Agrippinae excusavit ob imminentem partum [...] il s'excusa de ne pas faire revenir Agrippine, parce qu'elle était près d'accoucher

The direct object of Pliny's excusare seems to be [contra unum hominem] advocationem 'the legal assistance [against a single man]'. But Baeticis is dative. I can't see how it could be a part of that noun phrase (unless it were genitive), so it must go with the verb. So something like a dative of disadvantage? Pliny also supplies no real excuse, no reasons or circumstances, as explicitly mentioned in the dictionary entries and present in Tacitus. But perhaps he's free not to.
Is it strange to even think this complicated? How is this to be read?

@d_e Do you mean with me as the subject of excusare? I think I took that for granted and I don't see what difference it makes. Or what do you mean by "apposition" (which of course it can't be, strictly speaking)?

Upon re-reading I now I understand the Q better so deleted my comment. Anyway, I suggested to supply me as the object (not the subject) of excusare. something like: "to excuse [me] as an advocate to Baeticis" : i.e., not to be his layer.

@d_e That makes more sense. Dictionary entries for advocatio mention its use as collectively referring to the advocati present; perhaps this is possible also when the advocatio is only one person (Pliny).
